# Why does "System Information" want access to Contacts to auto-empty trash?

Tags: high-sierra, contacts, trash, system-information

macOS High Sierra – 10.13.3 (17D102)

I clicked Apple / About This Mac / Storage / Manage, and System Information app launches with a series of suggestions to reduce disk usage.

One suggestion is to empty the trash of items older than 30 days, which sounds appealing.

[image: Empty Trash Automatically option]

Upon clicking that, the green "completed" checkmark is added, but then macOS immediately asks for "System Information" to access my Contacts.

[image: System Info prompt]

Why is that? What does Contacts app specifically and uniquely have to do with auto-emptying the trash? Will it affect any cards in my Contacts that I've not manually deleted?

Comment: I just had this pop up randomly as well. I may be paranoid but it seems suspicious to me - especially since searching for this answer shows only a couple inquiries and they are both very recent. Would love to hear the solution. In the mean time, I am selecting "Don't Allow".